# XHTML & CSS: Can't seem to fit 3 images in one horizontal list?

Tags: html, css, image, margin

### Case

I am using HTML and CSS to try to display three images next to each others horizontally,
which I am using an unordered list to achieve.

### Issue

The two first images lines up just fine, but the third image seems to be placed below the list?

Here is a demonstration of the issue from inspecting the document.
li#illustrationItem3 is supposed to be 3rd in line, position just after **Image 2**.
[image: illustrationPiece3 misplaced.]
*illustrationItem3 appearing at a bad spot.*

---

Also, the division "illustrationContainer" seems to have a weird margin on the right,
even when "margin: 0px;" is specified.
[image: Inspection of illustrationContainer.]
*illustrationContainer appears to have a weird margin on the right.*

---

### HTML

```css
div#illustrationContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 780px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: 000000;
}
div#illustrationList {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 760px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li#illustrationItem1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 260px;
}
li#illustrationItem2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: -25px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 260px;
}
li#illustrationItem3 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: -25px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 260px;
}
img#illustrationPiece1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 260px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  content: url("/png/illustrationpieces/image_01.png");
}
img#illustrationPiece2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 260px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
  content: url("/png/illustrationpieces/image_02.png");
}
img#illustrationPiece3 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 260px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  content: url("/png/illustrationpieces/image_03.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="illustrationContainer">
  <ul id="illustrationList">
    <li id="illustrationItem1">
      <img id="illustrationPiece1" />
    </li>
    <li id="illustrationItem2">
      <img id="illustrationPiece2" />
    </li>
    <li id="illustrationItem3">
      <img id="illustrationPiece3" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*In advance; thanks for replies.*

Comment: If we run your code, it looks completely off. Check your code and make the snippet work. Also, your code is invalid HTML as your images lack the `src` attribute, which is mandatory. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Attributes

Comment: @connexo I have chosen to give the img-tag an ID and use CSS to give it content: "content: url("/png/illustrationpieces/image_01.png");".

Comment: Which doesn't make it any less invalid.

Comment: @connexo If that is invalid, it makes me confused when the images shows up in the document. I'd think the broken image link would show up in it's place if it was invalid.

Comment: Make no mistake, that is **not a matter of discussion**. The specs are totally clear on this: *The src attribute must be present, and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted.* https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-img-src

Comment: On top of that, using `content` on `img` shows even more lack of understanding as `img` elements **cannot have `content`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty - I made several changes to make your code more efficient as well as answered your question here.  The best way to do this on your end is to look at how I changed your code and compare it to what you had.

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p7hg07y9/1/)

```css
#illustrationContainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 780px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#illustrationList {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 20px); /* 80px */
  width: 760px;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

#illustrationItem1,
#illustrationItem2,
#illustrationItem3 {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

#illustrationItem1 {
  background: red; /* Take out background */
}

#illustrationItem2 {
  background: blue; /* Take out background */
}

#illustrationItem3 {
  background: green; /* Take out background */
}

#illustrationPiece1,
#illustionPiece2,
#illustionPiece3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#illustrationPiece1 {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  background-image: url("/png/illustrationpieces/image_01.png");
}

#illustrationPiece2 {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
  background-image: url("/png/illustrationpieces/image_02.png");
}

#illustrationPiece3 {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  background-image: url("/png/illustrationpieces/image_03.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="illustrationContainer">
  <ul id="illustrationList">
    <li id="illustrationItem1">
      <div id="illustrationPiece1"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="illustrationItem2">
      <div id="illustrationPiece2"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="illustrationItem3">
      <div id="illustrationPiece3"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answered my question.
I will clean up my code the way your code is.